# How to read the files in a folder recursively an asynchronously

Tags: flutter, file, stream

How can I read a folder contents (recursively) without blocking the main thread?

I have checked the Directory class and has 2 methods:

1. listSync to read the folder in a synchronous fashion
2. list to read the folder asynchronously but I don' really know when it finishes listing. This seems like a way to hear to folder content changes?

They both doesn't seem to be what I need.

Are isolates the only option left to read the files in a folder async?

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Directory-class.html - it has a sample code where `systemTempDir.list(...` lists the content recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use `toList()` method:

```
final directory = Directory('downloads');
final elements = directory.list(recursive: true).toList();
print(await elements);
```